# CSS selected state from hover to click

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, click, hover, selected

Apologies if this has been asked or is a dumb question - it seems simple, but I did search.

On my site, I use a navbar that I initially pulled from a site with many free canned navbars long ago, and have since changed it a lot since then by just tinkering with parameters.  Now, with the advent of mobile (yes, I'm behind), I want to change all my dropdown menus from popping out on hover to popping out on click.  I know this is how bootstrap does it, etc, so clearly it can be done.

For me, things start changing colors and appearing based on something like this:

```
.menu ul li.selected a.outer1 {color:#000; background:#929292; margin-bottom:250px; 
                               zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=60); opacity: 0.6; }
```

When the outer list element is selected, stuff changes.  However, it seems that the ".selected" makes the li "selected" on hover.  Is there a way to change it so it's selected on click?  Just a simple word change?  Or am I going to have to change my structure?  I can provide additional code if desired.

Comment: You will definitely get better answers if you provide additional code - there is not enough here to see what's going on.  You will get the best response if you create a small self-contained example, which contains only enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra.  Post this code into the question, or in a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/). Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Comment: And this would be the correct answer ^.  Sorry folks.  I thought .selected was a sub or pseudo class in CSS.  I completely forgot about a function I wrote in the JavaScript ready to add or remove class "selected" on hover!  DOH!  No wonder I couldn't find the same question!  Sorry again guys, and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a simple single CSS change.  The media queries loads a certain div for a specific viewport and hides another.

You should look at media queries and how you want to load/hide specific elements per viewport.